# Axios GET request to Spotify API returning 401

Tags: reactjs, axios, spotify

I used the format provided in this [spotify web api reference](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user-playlists/?limit=50&offset=0) and an access token generated from there directly, but I keep getting a 401 error.  What is going on?

```
    const accessToken = 'string from https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user-playlists/?limit=50&offset=0';
    console.log(accessToken);
    axios
        .get(
            'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
            { params: { limit: 50, offset: 0 } },
            {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }
        )
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Error:

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists?limit=50&offset=0 401
```

Comment: Does the `curl` example they give you also return a 401? If so, did you select the one mandatory scope for this request when you created the token?

Comment: no, the example works fine, and yes, I checked the scope 'playlist-read-private' scope before getting the token.  I added the error for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Post requests have a body in the second param and headers for the third param.  Get requests, however, have only the second param for both the URL parameters and headers.  So I just had to combine the 2 objects into one:

```
axios
    .get(
        'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists', {
            params: { limit: 50, offset: 0 },
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + newAccessToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
    )
```